# How to write mysql join query in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

```
select
spr.id,spr.total_marks,spr.obtained_marks,
p.paper_title ,p.exam_id,p.subject_id,
sr.reg_no,sr.student_id,
s.student_name
FROM 
students s,
student_registration sr,
student_paper_results spr,
papers p 
WHERE
s.id = sr.student_id AND
s.id = spr.student_id AND
p.id = spr.paper_id
```

how to write the above query in yii2 model. I want to write it in the form of Joins

Comment: How? You have to use fingers and keyboard. If you want it - do it! What did you tried until now?  We can fix your code, but we won't write it for you.

Comment: at least try something

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you so other having the same problem also get the benefit

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to write this query for `Yii2` using query builder, Active Record, DAO.

But since there is least information or effort added by your side not even the name of the models are provided. I would write the query with query builder [**`\yii\db\Query();`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html), these are simple [`joins`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#querying-data) that you should know if you are working in Yii.

```
$query=new \yii\db\Query();
$query
    ->select([new \yii\db\Expression('s.[[student_name]],spr.[[id]],spr.[[total_marks]],spr.[[obtained_marks]],p.[[paper_title]],p.[[exam_id]],p.[[subject_id]],sr.[[reg_no]],sr.[[student_id]],s.[[id]] as student_id')])
    ->from('students s')
    ->leftJoin('student_registration sr','sr.student_id=s.id')
    ->leftJoin('student_paper_results spr','spr.student_id=s.id')
    ->leftJoin('paper p','p.id=spr.paper_id')
    ->all();
```

If your `students` table model name is `Students` replace the first 2 lines of the above code with `Students::find()`